# Quickselect vs Countingselect

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, counting

Quickselect, based on quicksort, and counting select, based on counting sort.

Each is capable of finding the kth smallest element in an unsorted/sorted list/array.

However, I wish to write a set of guidelines to decide which of the two algorithms is most appropriate for specific situations. I need to think of situations, and than implement guidelines as to which algorithm is the better choice.

For this, I need a little help distinguishing which algorithm has specific strengths in certain areas, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** Count sort requires the elements to be [**enumerable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration) (There is a unique mapping of elements into integers) in order to work properly. Quick sort on the other hand, only require a well define compare op between every two elements (The compare function should be [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) - or intuitively - not self-contradicting). 

This is one main issue you should face - **the counting selection cannot always be used, while quick selection can.**

Why? Well, have a look at how [count sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) works, or specifically - how it determines the ordering between distinct element `a` and distinct element `b`: It uses its integer value to count how elements of this kind are in the collection. Have a look at the [pseudo-code in the wikipeida article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm). What I am refering to can be seen in this lines:

```
for each input item x:
    Count[key(x)] = Count[key(x)] + 1
```

The `key(x)` value, is the enumeration of the elements - if it does not exist, what will `key(x)` yield? and how will the algorithm work?

This also applies for the count select algorithm for the same reasons, it also uses the `key(element)` in order to count how much times this element repeats in the collection.

**(2)** One more issue is efficiency if the **range of elements** is huge - where counting is inefficient, since it is linear in the *range* of elements.

QuickSelect, based on quicksort run time is linear on average, but may sometimes decay to quadric time complexity.

**(3)** Another issue is **space** - count selection requires additional space, linear in the *range* of the elements, while quick-selection does not.

Comment: I don't quite understand the reason behind that, could you explain it in more depth?

Comment: Is counting selection more or less efficient than quickselect?

Comment: What exactly does enumerable mean, and when you say a well defined compare op, what does that entail exactly?

Comment: Okay. Do these reasons also apply for the selection version of the counting/quick algorithms?

Comment: Is there an example data set that is garunteed not to work for counting select?

Comment: @Andrew: You cannot enumerate [real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number), so you cannot use counting select on these. (unless you first sort them, and then enumerate the data according to the real order - but there is no point in doing this).

Comment: @Andrew: counting selection is about one order of magnitude slower than quickselect. The reason is that, if the chosen pivot is good enough, quickselect discards at lest 1/4 of the elements in each iteration. Counting select instead needs to deal with all of the elements. When *n*, the array size, increases, quickselect is about ten times faster than counting select.